# Convert Uppercase Letter Input to a specific Number

Tags: java

I'm super new to programming so I would love to keep this simple.  The compiler accepts my code, but when I run the program and type in for example the letter A I just get a ton of errors.  I tried earlier using String letter instead of int letter, but I just got compiler errors stating I couldn't convert Strings to characters or something.  I'm really confused and could use a quick explanation and fix so I can get a number back.   Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class PhoneAlgorithm {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int digit = -1;
        Scanner in;
        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an uppercase letter to find out the corresponding digit on a telephone: ");

        int letter;
        letter = Integer.parseInt(in.next());

        if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'B' || letter == 'C') {
            digit = 2;  }
        else if (letter == 'D' || letter == 'E' || letter == 'F') {
            digit = 3; }
        else if (letter == 'G' || letter == 'H' || letter == 'I') {
            digit = 4; }
        else if (letter == 'J' || letter == 'K' || letter == 'L') { 
            digit = 5; }
        else if (letter == 'M' || letter == 'N' || letter == 'O') {
            digit = 6; } 
        else if (letter == 'P' || letter == 'Q' || letter == 'R' || letter == 'S') {
            digit = 7; }
        else if (letter == 'T' || letter == 'U' || letter == 'V') {
            digit = 8; }
        else if (letter == 'W' || letter == 'X' || letter == 'Y' || letter == 'Z') {
            digit = 9; }
        else  if (letter >= 'a' && letter >= '3') {
            System.out.print("You did not enter a valid uppercase letter.  Try again!");
        }
        if (digit != -1) {
            System.out.println("The corresponding digit on your telephone is: " + digit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to list which errors you encounter, not just that you encountered errors.  (You can edit your post to include this information.)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `parseInt(str)`, you will get an `Exception` if the parameter `str` cannot be converted to an integer.

You must use `char`, since you are comparing the input with single characters:

```
char letter;
letter = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

- **`str.charAt(index)`** Returns the char value at the specified index.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked!  However, I've looked into charAt before and I'm extremely confused what this means.  I guess what I'm wondering is why does charAt have to be set to 0?  What exactly does this mean?  If you could point me to a site that would explain this well I'd appreciate it.  Every site I've read up on it has actually just confused me a whole lot more...

Comment: `str.charAt(0)` will return the first character in the `String`. If index is 1, it will return the second character. Why? Because indexes in programming starts with 0. So, `0` is first element, `1` is second element, so on.

Comment: Okay thanks Christian!  I fooled around a lot with the code and understand what's happening now.  I made some improvements with a while loop too!  My only other problem is whenever I simply press enter, without entering anything at all, the program crashes, and I've been trying to see if I can tell the code to recognize that I didn't enter anything at all and simply print an error rather than crash, but so far I haven't had any luck!

Comment: @user3255749 This is another question. I would need to see the code you have now, because you may have changed it. Try to research a little bit more, and then if you think is necessary, post a *new question* in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, I guess this is what you are looking for..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declarations
    char letter;
    int digit=0;


    // Asking the user to enterstring
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String enterString;


    //creating a scanner object and reading the string
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
    enterString= input.next();
    System.out.println("Entered string is "+enterString);

    int temp=0;

    for(int i=0;i<enterString.length();i++){
         letter=(char)enterString.codePointAt(i);

         if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'B' || letter == 'C') {
             digit = digit*10+2;  }
         else if (letter == 'D' || letter == 'E' || letter == 'F') {
             digit = digit*10+3; }
         else if (letter == 'G' || letter == 'H' || letter == 'I') {
             digit = digit*10+4; }
         else if (letter == 'J' || letter == 'K' || letter == 'L') { 
             digit = digit*10+5; }
         else if (letter == 'M' || letter == 'N' || letter == 'O') {
             digit = digit*10+6; } 
         else if (letter == 'P' || letter == 'Q' || letter == 'R' || letter == 'S') {
             digit = digit*10+7; }
         else if (letter == 'T' || letter == 'U' || letter == 'V') {
             digit = digit*10+8; }
         else if (letter == 'W' || letter == 'X' || letter == 'Y' || letter == 'Z') {
             digit = digit*10+9; }
         else  if (letter >= 'a' && letter >= '3') {
             System.out.print("You did not enter a valid uppercase letter.  Try again!");
         }
         /*if (digit != 0) {
             System.out.println("The corresponding digit on your telephone is: " + digit);
         }*/         
    }

    if (digit != 0) {
        System.out.println("The corresponding digit on your telephone is: " + digit);
    }

}

}
```